# Create an auto-follow back script in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm pretty sure this is a fairly simple operation, but after scouring other questions and the hopelessly outdated tweepy documentation, I've given up. I am trying to make an auto-follow back script... This is what I have so far.

```
def follow_back():
    followers=[api.followers()]
    following=[api.friends()]
    for follower in followers:
        if(follower in following):            
            print('did nothing for one person')
        else:
            api.create_friendship(follower)
            print('followed one person')
```

I get a "Page does not exist" tweepy error.

Comment: What is the rest of your error traceback? Do any of your `print` lines run?

Answer (score 3):

your syntax is wrong

```
    api.create_friendship(follower)
```

use something like this

```
    api.friendship.create(follower)
```

also you may want to define if you're requesting the screen_name or user ID ( _ID ) from followers.